# Overriding a Java class from Python using JCC. Is that possible?

Tags: java, python, pylucene, jcc

I'm using JCC to create a Python wrapper for a Java library and I need to override a method from a Java class inside the Python script. Is it possible? How can you do that if it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

you could create a proxy class in Python that calls the Java class. Then on the proxy class you can override whatever you need.

Comment: I can't use this solution because it is called on threaded code, so it is not just about execution, but execution and waiting for the results for a certain time.